# Angular CLI 7: Sass failed to compile

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli

few moments ago I installed Angular Cli 7 and started clean project by

```
ng new my-app
```

I selected precompiler SASS for css, but when I'm editing file styles.sass then is not working, my styles.sass looks like this

```
h1 { color: red }
```

but ng serve show this message

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/styles.sass
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.sass)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> h1 {    ^
>         Invalid CSS after "h1 {": expected "}", was "{"
>         in /Users/a/Documents/angular-projects/my-app/src/styles.sass
>   (line 1, column 5)

how to fix it? and why that's happen?

Comment: try to create like ng new my-app --style=scss

Answer (score 3):

- The CLI offers a command line flag to change your style when creating a new project with `ng new my-app --style=scss`
- As you can see, the extension is `.scss`, not `.sass` (at least for the syntax you're using, which is LESS)
- You are missing a semicolon `h1 { color: red; }`
- Remember to update your `angular.json` and component files accordingly if you don't reecreate a new project to resolve that

Comment: @William [`Les fichiers .sass sont identiques aux fichiers .scss mais les accolades sont remplacées par des tabulationx et les points-virgules par des retours à la ligne`](https://blog.soat.fr/2014/07/preprocesseurs-css-less-vs-sass/). Roughly translates to `sass files are identical to less files but brackets are replaced by tabs and caret returns by semicolons.`. And no, SASS and LESS aren't 2 versions of the same compiler. It just happens that sass can build LESS files.

Comment: A semi-colon isn't needed on the last statement of a CSS declaration block. Semi-colons are only needed to separate statements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#css_declaration_blocks

Answer (score 1):

Could be because you upgraded your node.
Try installing node-sass

npm install node-sass

More details about node-sass on
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Sadly, for me, this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

dude ... I think your sintaxe maybe be wrong, look at https://sass-lang.com/guide 
you shoulding use

```
h1
   color: red,
   align: center
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, tried everything including reinstalling all the packages and node itself and none of them helped.

Finally the project was cloned to **D:\somefolder** instead of the **Desktop** where I was cloning before. Then it compiled without any issues and worked fine.